# I am getting this error in my code saying Invalid use of void expression

Tags: c++, c++11

In the function  vector in_to_post(vector infix) (the vector=(1 + 2) * 3 ^ 4 ) is being converted to an output vector which is of the form (Postfix: 1 2 + 3 4 ^ *) and i am getting an error saying invalid use of void expression . I have commented the lines where i am getting this error.

```
    char get_optr(Token t) {
        // your code here
        return t.optr;
    }


vector<Token> in_to_post(vector<Token> infix) 
{
    vector<Token> output;
    // your code here
    stack<Token>b;
    for(int i=0;i<infix.size();i++)
    {
        if(is_opnd(infix[i]))
        {
             output.push_back (infix[i]);
        }
        else if(get_optr(infix[i])=='(')
        {
           b.push(infix[i]);
        }
       else if(get_optr(infix[i])==')')
        {
          while(b.empty()==false)
          {
              //char i=get_optr(b.pop());
            if(get_optr(b.pop())=='(')   // I am getting error here
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
               output.push_back(b.pop());  //error
            }
          }
        }
        else if(is_opnd(infix[i])==false)
        {
           // char i=infix[i];
            //char j=b.top();
            if((priority(infix[i])>priority(b.top()))||get_optr(infix[i])=='('||get_optr(infix[i])==')')
            {
                b.push(infix[i]);
            }
        }
        
    }
    while(b.empty()==false)
    {
        output.push_back(b.pop()); //error
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: [A decent `std::stack` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) will be very useful for this issue.

Comment: How is `Token` defined?  Is `Token` aliased to `void` or `void *`?

Comment: token is defined as an adt

Comment: struct Token {
    // your code here
    int opnd;
    char optr;
    bool isopnd;

};

Comment: Giving the line that triggers the error would be tremendously useful.

Comment: @VincentFourmond As OP says, the line that triggers the error is indicated by a comment in the code. It's quite clearly marked.

Comment: @cigien My bad, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [pop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) on a `std::stack` simply pops the top element off the stack, but doesn't return it. This function has a `void` return type, and if you try to use it in a context that requires a value, you get an error

```
output.push_back(b.pop());  //error
```

Instead, you can use [top](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) to get top element of the `std::stack`

```
output.push_back(b.top());  // ok
```

Note that this will simply return a reference to the top element without popping it. You can call `pop` after `top` to pop it.

Comment: @Tom No problem. Consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.